# Chrome doesn't block every popup I'm opening with javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, popup

I've coded this inside an Angularjs services:

```
.factory('NativePopup', function($rootScope){

    function open(data){
        var ref = window.open("components/modal-attesa.html", data.title, data.arg);

        if(!ref){
            $rootScope.showNotification({type: "error", message: "please enable popup"});
        }            
        return ref;
    }

    function close(ref){
        ref.close();
    }

    return {
        open: open,
        close: close
    }

})
```

And I have setted chrome with "Block every pop-up" without any exception. Now, when I call the `open` method

```
NativePopup.open(blah)
```

no matter what, chrome will always grant it. But if I put a breakpoint on the very first row of the `open` method, then I run the very same code inside my console, then chrome blocks it.

Anyone could explain me this behaviuor?

Comment: Was there some further clarification you needed on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean Chrome's "Do not allow any site to show pop-ups" under Settings > Privacy > Content Settings, that doesn't apply to popups that are opened in **direct** response to a user action, such as a click. E.g., if the user did some positive action and, *during* the event handler for that, JavaScript code calls `window.open`, it's not considered a "popup" as controlled by that setting.

E.g., this `window.open` will work (subject, probably, to some rate-limiting):

```
someElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
    window.open(/*...*/);
});
```

But this one won't:

```
someElement.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    window.open(/*...*/);
});
```

...because `mouseover` isn't considered a sufficiently positive user action to allow it.

This is the highly-successful compromise between literally disabling `window.open` completely, and allowing it willy-nilly, and is the default setting for most modern browsers.